# Не могу получить Scene в initialize JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Не понимаю как получить Scene, для того, чтобы получить действие клавиатуры

```
@FXML
private Label countLives;

@FXML
private Circle enemyCircle;

@FXML
private Circle myCircle;

@FXML
void initialize() {

    countLives.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(key -> {
        switch (key.getCode()) {
            case W:
                myCircle.setCenterX(myCircle.getCenterX() + 1);
        }
    });

}
```

Здесь countLives.getScene() выдает Null, но вот с кнопкой работает иначе, почему-то после нажатия у нее появляется Scene

```
void initialize(){
        labelNick.setText(client.getName());
        countReady.setText("1/10");
        System.out.println(buttonReady.getScene());
        buttonReady.setOnAction(event -> {
            buttonReady.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        }
```

Как в этом примере.
В общем вопрос заключается в том, как мне получить в контроллере Scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` выводится потому что на момент инициализации контроллера сцена еще не существует (в главном классе сначала загружается fxml, в этот же момент инициализируется контроллер, а потом уже создается объект сцены). В момент нажатия на кнопку же окно уже полностью инициализировано, поэтому объект сцены доступен.

Можно повесить `listener` на `sceneProperty`, при его изменении выполнять нужные вам действия со сценой:

```
countReady.sceneProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != null) {
        // 
    }
}));
```

Comment: Еще вопрос, я вот хочу задать движение моего круга по нажатию на кнопку, но ничего не происходит и экран почему-то прогружается через раз
```


@FXML
void initialize() {
  countLives.setText("10");
  myCircle.sceneProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != null) {
    myCircle.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(key -> {
    switch (key.getCode()) {
      case W:
        System.out.println(myCircle.getCenterX());
        myCircle.setCenterX(-5);
        myCircle.setCenterY(-10);
        myCircle.setRadius(100);

}
});

 }
}));
}


```

Comment: @Dazdraperm задайте вопрос отдельно